# a new numeration system

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-systems

Consider the sequences recursively defined by the function:

```
f(n)=(3^n+1)/2
```

such that:

```
s(0)=f(0)=1
s(1)=s(0)f(1)s(0)=1,2,1
s(2)=s(1)f(2)s(1)=1,2,1,5,1,2,1
s(3)=s(2)f(3)s(2)=1,2,1,5,1,2,1,14,1,2,1,5,1,2,1
........
```

Now I need to demonstrate mathematically, because I already checked by code, that every natural number can be represented by this sequence with the only weights 1 and -1 and the rule that the possible -1 occupy only the rightmost positions:

```
1->1
2->1+2-1
3->2+1
4->1+2+1
5->1+2+1+5-1-2-1
6->2+1+5+1-2-1
7->5+1+2-1
8->1+5+1+2-1
9->5+1+2+1
10->1+5+1+2+1
11->1+2+1+5+1+2-1
12->2+1+5+1+2+1
13->1+2+1+5+1+2+1
........
```

'->' means 'is represented as'

Comment: Does 2== have some relationship to s(1)? Does 3=={2,1} have any relationship to s at all?

Comment: check the text upgrade

Comment: Prove by induction on $n$ that all numbers below $f(n)$ can be represented in the desired way.

Comment: Not helping. Where does the -1 come from for 2? How does 3->{2, 1} have anything to do with s?

Comment: Read as: $3=2+1$, $6=2+1+5+1-2-1$, etc.